# Why can't I access my structure's internal ORD_SET structure?

Tags: scope, structure, sml, smlnj

This exercise I made up is intended to help me understand signatures, structures, and functors in Standard ML. I can't seem to get it to work. Just for reference, I'm using

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.75 [built: Sun Jan 20 21:55:21 2013]
```

I have the following ML signature for an "object for which you can compute magnitude":

```
signature MAG_OBJ =
sig
   type object
   val mag : object -> int
end
```

If I want to give a structure of "int sets with magnitude," I might have a structure for an ordered int to use with the standard library's ORD_SET signature as follows:

```
structure OrderedInt : ORD_KEY =
struct
   type ord_key = int
   val compare = Int.compare
end
```

Then I can create a functor to give me a structure with the desired types and properties:

```
functor MakeMagSet(structure ELT : ORD_KEY) : MAG_OBJ =
struct
   structure Set : ORD_SET = RedBlackSetFn(ELT)
   type object = Set.set
   val mag = Set.numItems
end
```

So far so good (everything compiles, at least). Now I create an instance of the structure for my OrderedInt structure I made above:

```
structure IntMagSet = MakeMagSet(structure ELT = OrderedInt)
```

But when I try to use it (create a set and compute its magnitude), I get an error:

```
val X = IntMagSet.Set.addList(IntMagSet.Set.empty, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

gives the error:

```
Error: unbound structure: Set in path IntMagSet.Set.empty.addList
```

From what I understand, ascribing a signature opaquely using :> makes it so one can't access any structure internals which are not defined explicitly in the signature, but I ascribed MAG_OBJ transparently, so I should be able to access the Set structure, right? What am I missing here?

[EDIT]

Even rewriting the functor to specifically bind the functions I want to the struct is no good:

```
functor MakeMagSet(structure ELT: ORD_KEY) : MAG_OBJ =
struct
   structure Set : ORD_SET = RedBlackSetFn(ELT)
   type object = Set.set
   val mag = Set.numItems
   val empty = Set.empty
   val addList = Set.addList
end
```

Trying to access "empty" and "addList" give unbound variable errors.

On the other hand, trying to explicitly define the Set structure outside of the struct and use its functions gives a type error upon calling mag:

```
Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: IntMagSet.object
  operand:         Set.set
  in expression:
    IntMagSet.mag X
```

Comment: Just realized I can't say "IntMagSet.Set.empty.addList", because I'm silly and got too used to object oriented style. I think there's still a problem here, but I have to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you explicitly said that the type of `MakeMagSet` makes a `MAG_OBJ`, whose signature does not contain `Set`. If you had gotten rid of the `: MAG_OBJ` or made `MAG_OBJ` include `ORD_SET`, then it will work.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have every MAG_OBJ include an ORD_SET, because what if I want to "compute magnitudes" on things that aren't sets?

Comment: It seems that putting : MAG_OBJ does not simply verify that the resulting structure complies with an interface, but restricts it to do so. Removing : MAG_OBJ does indeed fix the problem. Now if I use it in, e.g. another functor, I can still put : MAG_OBJ and have it use the mag function, but then I can't refer to the underlying set anymore. This makes me wonder why type ascription in a functor is even a feature; it renders my structure completely useless!